# Why do I get "Uncaught TypeError: navigator.bluetooth.getAvailability is not a function"

Tags: web-bluetooth

The following code, executing on a chromebook with Chrome version  59.0.3071.134 (Official Build) (64-bit) is generating "Uncaught TypeError: navigator.bluetooth.getAvailability is not a function". Any idea why?

```
bluetoothle.checkBluetoothAvailable = function() {
  console.log("checkBluetoothAvailable");
  navigator.bluetooth.getAvailability().then(isAvailable => {
    document.getElementById('btn_discover').hidden = !isAvailable;
    if (!isAvailable) {
      document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = 'Bluetooth is not available';
    }
  });
  navigator.bluetooth.addEventListener('availabilitychanged', e => {
    document.getElementById('btn_discover').hidden = !e.value;
    if (!e.value) {
      document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = 'Bluetooth is not available';
    } else {
      document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = 'Bluetooth is available';
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getAvailability is not implemented. It is specified, so it makes sense to try it and expect it to work.

https://github.com/WebBluetoothCG/web-bluetooth/blob/gh-pages/implementation-status.md lists what has been implemented in more detail.

And, in the specification you will find the background of some sections such as [getAvailability](https://webbluetoothcg.github.io/web-bluetooth/#dom-bluetooth-getavailability) include "This section is not stable." and background text "Unstable".

Comment: Ok, got it. Thanks :-)